# How can I declare a dependency in package.json using its own git repository?

Tags: npm, repository, package.json, npm-scripts

I am trying to declare an npm package that is in the same repository and directory. How can I do that?

Comment: `npm i /location/of/dependency` - just make sure that it has its own `package.json` file

Comment: @evolutionxbox To have its own `package.json` it must be in a separate directory, no? At least in a subdirectory?

Comment: @phd yes. At least I don't know which file `npm` would use if there are more than two in a directory.